# How to find the regions for which the derivative of my function changes sign?

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I have an energy function of the angles of the  electrons' spins. th1 is vector with (2l+2) elements and each element represents the angle of an individual electron spin. I need to eventually find the angles for which my energy is minimum. (I can use NMinimize but I want to make sure that my answer is the Global minimum, so I want to figure out the derivative first and see how many minimum my function has).

So I am taking the derivative of the function, and using Reduce to find different regions, but it takes forever ant does not give me the answer. Any idea how I can find the regions for which my derivative changes sign so I can figure out where the minimums are?

```
  \[ScriptL]0 = 5
  \[Gamma] = 
  Table[{Riffle[Range[0, -\[ScriptL]0, -1], Range[\[ScriptL]0]][[i]], 
  1}, {i, 1, 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1}];
  th1 = Table[Subscript[t, n] , {n, 1, 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 2}]
  deriv = Table[1, {n, 1, 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 2}]

  factorFxn[\[ScriptL]_, m1_, m2_, p1_, p2_] := 

  If[\[Gamma][[p1, 1]] - \[Gamma][[m1, 1]] == \[Gamma][[m2, 
 1]] - \[Gamma][[p2, 1]], 
 Sum[(2 \[ScriptL] + 1)^2 Sum[
 If[\[Gamma][[p1, 1]] - \[Gamma][[m1, 1]] == 
    mval && \[Gamma][[m2, 1]] - \[Gamma][[p2, 1]] == 
    mval, (-1)^(\[Gamma][[m1, 1]] + \[Gamma][[m2, 1]] + 
      mval) ThreeJSymbol[{\[ScriptL], -\[Gamma][[m1, 
       1]]}, {\[ScriptL], \[Gamma][[p1, 
      1]]}, {\[ScriptL]temp, -mval}] ThreeJSymbol[{\[ScriptL]temp,
      mval}, {\[ScriptL], -\[Gamma][[m2, 
       1]]}, {\[ScriptL], \[Gamma][[p2, 
      1]]}] ThreeJSymbol[{\[ScriptL], 0}, {\[ScriptL], 
     0}, {\[ScriptL]temp, 0}]^2, 
   0], {mval, -\[ScriptL]temp, \[ScriptL]temp}], {\[ScriptL]temp, 
   0, 2 \[ScriptL]}], 0]



 energy[th1_] :=(*(2 \[ScriptL]0 +1)^2*) Sum[
 (* Find out which states we're calculating the matrix element of *)    

 (Cos[th1[[p2]]] Cos[th1[[p1]]] + 
  Cos[th1[[p2]]] Sin[th1[[p1 + 1]]] + 
  Cos[th1[[p1]]] Sin[th1[[p2 + 1]]] + 
  Sin[th1[[p2 + 1]]] Sin[th1[[p1 + 1]]] + 
  If[p1 == p2, Cos[th1[[p1]]] Sin[th1[[p1 + 1]]], 
   0]) factorFxn[\[ScriptL]0, m1, m2, p1, p2]

 , {p1, 1, 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1}, {m1, 1, 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1}, {p2, 1, 
  p1}, {m2, 1, m1}];
  
 derivative = Map[D[energy[th1], #] &, th1[[1 ;; 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 2]]]

  th1[[1]] = 0.000001;
  th1[[2 \[ScriptL]0 + 2]] = \[Pi]/2;
  Reduce[derivative == 0 && 
  0 < th1[[2 ;; 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1]] <= \[Pi]/2, 
  th1[[2 ;; 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1]]]
```

Comment: Try `Map[D[energy[th1], #] &, th1[[1 ;; 5]]]`

Comment: Thank you so much, it gives me the derivative, Do you have any suggestions how to find the regions it changes sign? @UlrichNeumann

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I am using Reduce but it seems it takes forever to solve.

Comment: by the way, I'm not sure `th1[[1]] = 0.000001` does what you might mean it to. it sets the first part of the list `th1` to `0.000001`; it doesn't set the symbol *at* that first place, i.e. `Subscript[t,1]` to `0.000001`! for that, use `Evaluate[th1[[1]]] = 0.000001`.

Comment: (Also, for convenience, by the way, instead of using `th1[[2 ;; 2 \[ScriptL]0 + 1]]`, you can simply use `Rest[th1]`!)

Comment: I wanted to fix the first and the last angle to be 0.000001 and pi/2.

Comment: @thorimur I want th1={1.*10^-6, Subscript[t, 2], Subscript[t, 3], Subscript[t, 4], \
Subscript[t, 5], Subscript[t, 6], Subscript[t, 7], Subscript[t, 8], \
Subscript[t, 9], Subscript[t, 10], Subscript[t, 11], \[Pi]/2}

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi oh, ok. I don't think `th1` appears anywhere in the following code after that assignment, though (it's already been evaluated into `Subscript[t, n]`'s), so this would have no effect; as such I assumed you wanted `Subscript[t, 1]` to have the value `0.000001`.

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi Even if you find the regions where sign changes it's not trivial to decide if a global maximum was found!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann But at least I can see where the local minimums are, and calculate the energy in that area to see with one is lower, what is the reason that you think it won't help?

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi If you know `derivative==0` you cannot conclude wether it's a local or global extremum , I think

Comment: No I cannot, but I can calculate the energy around various minima and compare them to see which one is lower